# Automatically logout of cinnamon after period of idle

Tags: fedora, cinnamon

I have been searching around and I have been unable to find something that can logout of a cinnamon session after a period of inactivity. I am running Fedora 21 and I do not want something that will close a bash shell after a period of time, but close cinnamon entirely. It would be great if there was a solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve it with:

```
dconf write /org/cinnamon/settings-daemon/plugins/power/sleep-inactive-ac-timeout TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS
dconf write /org/cinnamon/settings-daemon/plugins/power/sleep-inactive-ac-type 'logout'
```

Replace TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS with your preferred value